# How do I bypass code in the RunWorkerCompleted event if an error occurs?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I wrote a program that creates an XML file from the contents of an Excel spreadsheet.  The program works and I am now making it more robust by adding error checking.  For example, if the Excel spreadsheet does not contain a required XML tag, the program displays an error and returns from the main program.  When an error occurs, the RunWorkerCompleted() event fires, and code executes that shouldn't execute because an error occurred.  My question is how to determine if an error occurred so I can bypass certain code in the RunWorkerCompleted() event.

I tried calling bgw.CancelAsync() in the main program where the error is detected, but RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e.Cancelled is false so it doesn't work.

Here are some excerpts from my code.  The progress bar is started in the click event of a button.  It works, but I had to declare cellsProcessed, rowCount, and colCount as global because I couldn't figure out how to pass them to bgw_DoWork().

```
private void button_create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Define the event that fires when the progress bar finishes
   bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += bgw_Complete;

        rowCount = xmlRange.Rows.Count; // Declared as global
        colCount = xmlRange.Columns.Count;  // Declared as global

        // Start the progress bar thread
        if (!bgw.IsBusy)
        {
            bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        // Read the header in row 1 and return an error if it isn't valid
        for (colIdx = 1; colIdx <= colCount; colIdx++)
        {
            if ((xmlRange.Cells[1, colIdx] != null) && (xmlRange.Cells[1, colIdx].Value2 != null))
            {
                cellContents = xmlRange.Cells[1, colIdx].Value2.ToString();

                switch (colIdx)
                {
                    case 1:
                        if (cellContents != "Tag")
                        {
                            error = true;
                            errText = "Cell A1 must contain 'Tag'";
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if (cellContents != "Type")
                        {
                            error = true;
                            errText = "Cell B1 must contain 'Type'";
                        }
                        break;
   if (error)
   {

      bgw.CancelAsync();
      MessageBox.Show(errText, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

      // Close Excel resources
      xmlWorkbook.Close();
      xmlSpreadsheet.Quit();
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xmlRange);
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xmlWorksheet);
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xmlWorkbook);
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xmlSpreadsheet);
      GC.Collect();

      return;
   }

    private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (bgw.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            label_pctComplete.Text = "Completed " + progressBar.Value.ToString() + "%";
            bgw.ReportProgress((100 * ++cellsProcessed) / (rowCount * colCount));
        }
    }

    private void bgw_Complete(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Cancelled)
        {
            label_pctComplete.Visible = false;
            progressBar.Visible = false;

            // Inform the user that the XML file was created
            label_created.Visible = true;
            label_created.Text = "Done!...Created " + textBox_outputFile.Text;

            // Enable the button so the user can view the XML Limit File
            button_openLimitFile.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void bgwProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I modified my original code to add a DoWork handler.  I had to declare rowCount and colCount as global to Form1 to get it to work because I couldn't figure out how to pass these values from the main program to bgw_DoWork.  However, the main issue remains:  bgw_Complete fires when my parser detects an error in the switch (colIdx) statement but e.Cancelled is true so the code in the if block executes.  I don't want it to execute if the backgroundworker has been cancelled.  Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!